# Template argument deduction of return type

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

How is the return type here being deduced? **In other words**, how based on the return type of the function pointer does it instantiate the correct function.

```
template<typename From, typename To>
To Convert(const From& f) 
{
    std::cout << sizeof(From) << " " << sizeof(To) << std::endl;    
    return To(f);
}



int main()
{
    float (*p)(const double &e) = Convert;
    p(20.2);

}
```

This prints

```
8 4
```

Comment: You are assigning `Convert` to a function pointer `p` whose signature is explicitly `float (*)(const double &)`, so `From=double` and `To=float` are simply being deduced from that signature, as those are the only deduced template values that can satisfy the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that return types cannot be deduced in a function **call** even if there is context that could be used:

```
template<class T> T get();
struct X {} x=get();  // error: cannot deduce T
```

No type except (reference to) *cv* `X` could work here, but you just don't consider that it is exactly the initializer of a variable.

However, return types can be deduced when a function is **named** in a context where a particular type is ["obviously" expected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address), as in the question, as well as when conversion function templates are used (since there's nothing else *to* deduce).